# How to install Emmet.io (former zen coding) on Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu Precise?

Tags: 12.04, sublime-text

Or in other words, has any of you been able to install [pyv8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) and [google v8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) without pain?

Hello, everyone... well, my question is regarding to install the emmet.io plugin on Sublime Text 2 but so far I can find and easy & straightforward to install it.

Thanks in advance for your time. This is the url to the plugin https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that (or at least it works for me, without installing anything else) that Ubuntu Precise 64 bits already have pyv8 and google v8.

I just simple git clone emmet plugin and it works immediately